# Sub Menu content is being duplicated

Tags: plugin-development, menus, admin-menu, add-submenu-page

In the plugin I am developing I am using the following code to build my menu -

```
add_menu_page('BCRM Plugin Settings', 'BCRM',
    'administrator', __FILE__, 'bcrm_settings_page', BOOGIE__PLUGIN_URL .
    '_inc/img/icon_settings.png');
add_submenu_page( __FILE__, 'BCRM Customer Settings', 'Customer Settings',
    'administrator', 'BCRM', 'bcrm_customer_settings_page');
add_submenu_page( __FILE__, 'BCRM Form Settings', 'Form Settings',
    'administrator', 'BCRM', 'bcrm_form_settings_page');
```

My functions are built like this -

```
function bcrm_settings_page() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    require_once( BOOGIE__PLUGIN_DIR . 'views/options.php' );
}

function bcrm_customer_settings_page() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    require_once( BOOGIE__PLUGIN_DIR . 'views/customer_settings.php' );
}

function bcrm_form_settings_page() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    require_once( BOOGIE__PLUGIN_DIR . 'views/form_settings.php' );
}
```

When ever I view the contents of these menus, they look to be loading my views twice. So if I click on Customer Settings, I get the content of both views loading like this -

> Customer Relations Management This is the customers page.
>
> Customer Relations Management This is the forms page.

What am I doing that is causing my two views to load on every page?

Answer (score 1):

I was using the same page name for both.

You can see in this snippet that I used "BCRM" and I didn't realize it.

```
add_submenu_page( __FILE__, 'BCRM Customer Settings', 'Customer Settings',
    'administrator', '**BCRM**', 'bcrm_customer_settings_page');
add_submenu_page( __FILE__, 'BCRM Form Settings', 'Form Settings',
    'administrator', '**BCRM**', 'bcrm_form_settings_page');
```

I changed them to BCRM_customers and BCRM_forms respectively and it is now 100% functional.

This was a silly mistake that came from not carefully reading. If you see duplications, check for duplicate page names.